# class Imports generating infinite loop?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've recently experienced an error that may have taken down the whole web server. I'm relatively new to web programming (2 years experience... kinda). But I think I may have narrowed down what may have happened and want to ask if it's possible. I think it is.

I have 2 classes that I keep in the `App_Code` directory. One handles **logging**. The other handles **emails**.

I had set up the logging class to send an email alert if there is an error log generated. Then I set up the email system to generate a log if an email is sent. Both reference the other class to do this.

Could this be an "infinite loop" scenario??

I may have induced a "broadcast storm" by doing this, taking down the whole server... which is a set of virtual servers. So, the question is kinda important :)

I did do some looking around, searching for "infinite loop class reference" but didn't find anything but super technical writing.

Comment: Well I guess my first question would be, Did you receive a few hundred thousand emails?

Comment: I did create a broadcast storm (D'oh!) and took down the whole virtual server set up! I consider this a lesson learned!

Comment: thumbs up on your subtle humor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a definite possibility. Either set the email class to not log messages when sending log e-mails, or set the log class to not email log entries about sending e-mails (or both).

Comment: Yeah, the more I thought about it the more I knew I was right. See my other note above. And I had thought of your answer on how to avoid... send the email via code local to the logging class... and log via code local to the email handler class. Thanks.